# the number of solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \pmod m$ is $\prod_{p \mid m} \left(1+ \left(\dfrac{a}{p} \right) \right).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Suppose that $m$ is odd. Show that if $\gcd(a,p) = 1$ then the number of solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \mod m$ is $\displaystyle \prod_{p \mid m} \left(1+ \left(\dfrac{a}{p} \right) \right).$ Show that this holds for all integers $a$ if $m$ is an odd square-free number.

Not really sure how to approach this problem. There are $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ quadratic residues mod $p$ and this is congruent to $\left(\dfrac{a}{p} \right).$ But this is the case where $p$ is prime and not an arbitrary odd integer. Additionally, since $\gcd(a,p) = 1,$ we have $\left(\dfrac{a^2}{p} \right) = 1,$ $\left(\dfrac{a^2b}{p} \right) = \left(\dfrac{b}{p} \right).$ How do we prove the above proposition?

Comment: If $a$ is not a QR of $p$ for some divisor $p$ of $m$, then there are no solutions, and since $1+(a/p)=0$, the formula gives the right answer. In all other cases, the formula says that the number of solutions is $2^t$ where $t$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $m$. This can be proved by a Chinese Remainder Theorem argument.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am aware of the Chinese Remainder theorem, but am having trouble seeing how the isomorphism applies. Would we just use the ring $\mathbb{Z}/ap\mathbb{Z}$ decomposed into the direct product $\mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will use more number theoretic language. For simplicity assume $m=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes such that $a$ is a QR of each. We have $x^2\equiv a\pmod{m}$ iff $x^2\equiv a$ modulo each of $p$ and $q$. The congruence modulo $p$ has $2$ solutions, say $x\equiv \pm b\pmod{p}$. The congruence odulo $q$  has $2$ solutions,  say $x\equiv \pm c\pmod{q}$.  Consider the $2^2=4$ systems of congruences $x\equiv \pm b\pmod{p}$, $x\equiv \pm d\pmod{q}$. Each system has a solution which is a solution of $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$.

Comment: @user167857 : Kindly look at *Theorem 2.20* in Nivens book on Introduction to the theory of numbers. He proves the following: If $f(x)$ be a fixed polynomial with integral coefficients and for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ let $N(m)$ denote the number of solutions to the congruence $f(x) \equiv 0\pmod{m}$. If $m= \prod p^{a}$ then $N(m)= \prod N(p^{a})$. Though Andre has given you the correct idea looking at Niven's book for a complete proof might be helpful.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. That is very helpful. But I am still curious on how to apply the chinese remainder theorem and phrase this in more algebraic language. It seems that you are suggesting the isomorphism would be $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}q\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @S.C. Okay I will look at the theorem, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user167857: The isomorphism also does it.  There are $2$ first components whose square  is $a$. There are also $2$ second components whose square is $a$. Combining in all possible ways gives $4$ items whose square is $a$. If we have $t$ primes, the same idea gives $2^t$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understand your comment, but how the $2^t$ possible solutions equivalent to $\displaystyle \prod_{p \mid m} \left(1+ \left(\dfrac{a}{p} \right) \right).$?

Comment: Since for all the primes $p_i$ we have that $a$ is a QR of $p_i$, the Legendre symbol $(a/p_i)$ is $1$ for all $i$, and therefore $1+(a/p_i)=2$. By the way, I hesitate to write an answer, since apart from the kind of silly $1+(a/p)$, stuff close to this has appeared on MSE before, and at least one answer, possibly more, has been by me.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for clarifying. And no problem. Could you possibly provide a link to one of these similar answers?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am awful at searching, and the MSE search facilities are not good. A number of the questions treat the  problem of counting the solutions of $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. There instead of $\pm c,\pm d$ one is using $\pm 1,\pm 1$.